# Can't see schemas for DB2 ex-c in eclipse jun, but I can query with scrape book

Tags: jpa, db2, java-ee-6, eclipse-juno

StackOverflow, I need your help.

I am developing a J EE application, but I ran into a road block. I'm currently setting up my environment to utilize *IBM DB2 Express-C* and WASCE on *Windows 7* with *Eclipse Juno J EE* version. Both technologies are working fine, I can access WASCE through browser and I can access my *DB2* instance through *Data Studio 3.1.1* and I can access existing databases and create schemas, tables, perform queries...

My issue comes into play when I try to create a data connection profile through Eclipse so that I can use the *JPA* tools in order to reverse engineer a schema. So, I create a connection profile with the Jars from Ex-c (`db2jcc.jar`, `db2jcc_license_cu.jar`) and the following properties:

```
Connection URL: jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/DBNAME
Database Name: DBNAME
Driver Class: com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
Password: ****
User ID: USERNAME

Test Connection Result: "Ping Succeeded!"
```

So, I click okay and now have the Connection Profile established. So, I click the twisty and see DBNAME, click DBNAME, click Catalogs, click DBNAME, click Schemas...

and nothing!

I open SQL Scrapbook, perform a simple query: "Select * from schema.table" and I get the result back, which is the correct data that I put into the database through Data Studio.

So, I try to use the JPA Tools and just like I guessed, it doesn't register any tables through the connection profile, so it doesn't work. Furthermore, when establishing JPA my entities (made by hand) yell at me because it says that the table doesn't exist, and the fields don't correspond. Or something like that.

I need your help to establish a correct connection profile through Eclipse Juno Java EE with DB2 Exc!

Comment: I also am experiencing this exact problem. There is an eclipse bug open in their tracker now..
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398408

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue when working with Eclipse Kepler.  In Eclipse go to Help > Install New Software.  In the Work with: paste in the address http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/downloads/drops/M_updates_1.11.2/ and complete the rest of the process.  This solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be resolved due to the closure of this bug:

Bug 416722 – Can't view schemas since db2 V9.7 FP6: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=416722

According to the bug report, this functionality should be in forthcoming DTP 1.11.2. The update URL for DPT 1.11.2 Milestone is:

http://download.eclipse.org/datatools/downloads/drops/M_updates_1.11.2